# Problems with a custom route in ASP.NET-MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I am having problems with Html.ActionLink when I have a route that takes one parameter.
I have the following routers in global.asx:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            "materias",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id},{titulo_materia}.html",
            new { controller = "materias", action = "Index", id = "", titulo_materia = "" }  
        );
```

When I use ActionLink passing two parameters, everything works ok.
But when I try to create a link using the first route I end up with something like:

http://meusite.com/controller-name/[parameter],.html

EDIT:

Here is the action link that i`m having problems:

```
<span class="editar"><%=Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edit", "Users", new { id = this.Model.login }, null)%></span>
```

This link is on another page that is used to manage user data.

Comment: Post your Html.ActionLink code

Comment: i edited my post with the actionlink code.

Comment: What happens if you move the second route rule before the first?

Comment: Action Link with two paramters: http://meusite/[controller]/[action]/5?titulo_materia=foobar, Action link with one paramters works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should put your most generic route at the bottom.

Then, how about doing something like :

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "materias",
        "{materias}/{action}/{id},{titulo_materia}.html",
        new { controller = "materias", action = "Index", id = "", titulo_materia = "" }  
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",                                              // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
    );
```

This way , the materias route only works for the materias controller. (not tested)

**EDIT:**
htmm .. try using martin's example with a small addition :

```
Html.RouteLink("Link Title", new { controller = "Controller", Action= "Action",id = this.Model.login });
```

Comment: I tested it... But i`m getting same result. When i try create a link using actionlink with two paramters i get something like "http://meusite.com/controllerName/[first-paramters]?titulo_materia=foobar

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Html.RouteLink("Link Title", new { controller = "Controller", Action= "Action" });
```

Comment: @Martin, but i have to pass ID of the user to get user information.